# Getting Guava ArrayListMultimap to work

Tags: java, guava

I'm relatively new to java, and am working on a new analysis method to improve my current implementation of (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26577172/inefficcient-optimally-deleting-2s-rows-and-columns-from-a-random-mod2).

I've determined that I want a multimap to process my dataset. Thus, I downloaded Guava and placed the ~2MB file into a directory. I compile my program using Multimap or ArrayListMultimap with:

```
javac -classpath C:\mywork\guava-18.0.jar myfile.java
```

---

Edit: At the advice of user2336315, I changed the code to:

```
ArrayListMultimap<String, int[]> combinations = ArrayListMultimap.create();
```

This compiles perfectly. However, I then get another error when I run the script with 'java Optimize':

To see how to run the code properly after compiling, please refer to the answer comments below.

---

Here's my current test code:

```
import java.util.Random;
import com.google.common.collect.ArrayListMultimap;    

class Determine {
    public static int[][] rando() {
        // Various lines of code to product a random matrix
    }
}

class Search {
    public static void finalize(int[][] a) {
        int bluejay =  a.length;
        int minimum = 1;

        ArrayListMultimap<String, int[]> combinations = ArrayListMultimap.create();
        for (int x = 0; x < bluejay - minimum + 1; x++) {
            int y = 0;
            while (y < 5) {
                int[] rows = new int[x + 1];
                rows[0] = 1;
                combinations.put(Integer.toString(x), rows);
                y += 1;                 
            }
            System.out.println(combinations);
        }
    }
}

public class Optimize {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] matrix  = Determine.rando();
        Search.finalize(matrix);
    }
}
```

Comment: `javac -classpath` yikes, there are IDEs for that. Btw `ListMultiMap<String, int[]>` is a `Map<String, List<int[]>>`, is the list of arrays part intentional?

Comment: Yes. Because I will be taking the combinations of a set of K elements. Each element in map corresponds to (k choose n) with n <= k. Next, each (k choose n) will contain a series of combinations (each represented by a list, or a subset of K). This won't blow up due to the nature of my algorithm when it's finished, however.

Comment: Ok, "I'm only about 3 weeks into java" and `ListMultiMap<String, int[]>` sound pretty unlikely :D

Comment: I had a summer class in python last year as my first programming course which taught me a few of the basics (which is why I'm trying to implement something similar to a dictionary). Other than that, my university java course is pretty fast paced (no-where near this material yet however) -_-. But this is off-topic :D

Comment: Ok, maybe it's more like 7 weeks since the second exam is coming up soon. My bad!

Comment: Since you've marked an answer as accepted, there's no need to put "Solved" in the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructors of the class are private, you cannot see them outside the class. You have to use the static method that creates the map.

```
ArrayListMultimap<String, int[]> combinations = ArrayListMultimap.create();
```

As for the second error, I don't see any Guava class with this name, so maybe you mispelled it?

Comment: Worked. However, now I get another error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError. Caused by ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.collect.ArrayListMultimap. Various details about URL ClassLoaders etc. I'm looking into why now, but am writing this to get it out quickly.

Comment: @user3834916 Did you add the library to the build path?

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little more? I imported the class correctly to the best of my knowledge (updated code) and directed the class path to the right directory. Do I need to do something else?

Comment: @user3834916 you need to supply the `-classpath` argument to both `javac` and `java`. Libraries are not compiled into the result, so you need to tell java at runtime again where they are.

Comment: Ah, I thought it my be something like that. However, how do i implement this? Typing 'java -classpath C:\mywork\guava-18.0.jar Optimize' doesn't work. It can't find my main method. Also, could you recommend a source for me to read about this process more in depth?

Comment: Looking into other stackoverflow posts for this new problem. Thanks for all the advice!

Comment: @user3834916 that's something I've never had a problem with because I am using an IDE which does that for me :) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_%28Java%29#Setting_the_path_of_a_Jar_file looks good I guess. I guess `java -classpath ".;C:\mywork\guava-18.0.jar" Optimize` should work - you need the path of both your own `.class` files (the `.` is the current directoy) and the library